# Добавление класса к div при наведении на ссылку и блок, следующий за ссылкой (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как правильно написать код, чтобы при наведении на ссылку и блок, следующий за ссылкой (выпадающее меню) к искомой ссылке добавлялся класс?

Нынешний "вариант"

```
$('.menu__link').mouseover(function(event) {
        $('.menu__link').addClass('menu__link_active');
    });

    $('.menu__link').mouseover(function(event) {
        $('.menu__link').removeClass('menu__link_active');
    });
```

Как видно, думаю, он очень дегроидный и если не использовать вторую часть кода с remove - класс добавляется сразу ко всем элементам с .menu__link.

```
$('.menu__link').mouseover(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('menu__link--active');
});
```

Если использую таким образом - класс добавляется к требуемому элементу, но не исчезает.

Разметка

```
li.nav-menu__item
    a.nav-menu__link(href="#").
        Элемент навигации

    //выпадающее меню
    .nav-menu__sub-menu
        ul.nav-sub-menu
            li.b-nav-sub-menu__item.
                Элемент выпадающего меню
            li.b-nav-sub-menu__item.
                Элемент выпадающего меню
```

Comment: Раскрытие доп меню делается на чистом css, зачем Вам js здесь? Приведите разметку, чтобы все увидели структуру меню

Comment: Сайт должен работать на IE8, потому приходится использовать js для верстки больше, чем хотелось бы. Добавил разметку.

Comment: IE8 нормально же дружит с css. Или нет? Вы пробовали на чистом css реализовать?

Comment: И откуда взялся класс `js-nav-menu__link`? Когда у Вас используется `nav-menu__link`

Comment: Поправил, сократил классы для образца.  Нюанс в том, что отображение меню идет через slideUp/slideDown, а если делать выделение ссылки при наведении на ссылку и выпадаюшее под ней меню - выходит как-то громоздко.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li.nav-menu__item
  a.nav-menu__link(href="#").
    Элемент навигации

  //выпадающее меню
    ul.nav-sub-menu
        li.b-nav-sub-menu__item.
            Элемент выпадающего меню
        li.b-nav-sub-menu__item.
            Элемент выпадающего меню
```

Во-первых, дочерний nav Вам ни к чему, постарайтесь избавиться от него по возможности. Во-вторых, общий принцип такой:

```css
ul.nav-menu{
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.nav-menu li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
ul.nav-menu li a{
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}
ul.nav-menu li:hover>a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.nav-menu li ul{
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul.nav-menu li ul li{
  float: none;
}
ul.nav-menu li ul li a{
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #ff0000;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.nav-menu li:hover>ul{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-menu__item">
    <a href="#!" class="nav-menu__link">Пункт меню</a>
    <ul class="nav-sub-menu">
      <li class="b-nav-sub-menu__item">
        <a href="#!">Дочерний пункт меню</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-nav-sub-menu__item">
        <a href="#!">Дочерний пункт меню</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-nav-sub-menu__item">
        <a href="#!">Дочерний пункт меню</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-menu__item">
    <a href="#!" class="nav-menu__link">Пункт меню</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но один момент - не выходит сделать так, чтобы эффект от ховер на Пункте меню оставался при открытом меню, т.е. если я убираю курсор с пункта меню на открывшееся меню - эффект остается висеть.

Comment: В смысле пропадает выпадающее меню когда убираете курсор с него? Или что?

Comment: Пропадает выделение ссылки "пункт меню", если перевожу курсор на выпадающее меню, как раз это и хотел сделать через js, т.к. не получалось с css

Comment: @Abaddorer не получается потому, что выпадающее меню не расширяет родительский элемент вниз, по сути, находится вне его. Мой пример не работает? Какой браузер?

Comment: Само выпадающее меню срабатывает. Браузер хром.

Comment: @Abaddorer Немного поправил код, Вы это имели в виду?

Comment: Да, оно самое, спасибо.